# Not Replacing Car Starter

Tags: battery, starting, car, starter, power

I have a problem with my car starter. I believe this was a problem on my car starter since I have a mechanic who went to my office and have it check. He says the battery is ok.
When I start the car, sometimes it cranks so i have to start it again and again until it starts, sometimes you have to start it several times for it to start which eventually starts

My question is, Is it ok, not to have it fixed? Will this cause problems in the future if I decided not to have it fix?

Comment: If it is a "starter problem" which you don't fix, at some time the starter will fail to work and the car won't start at all. If that's what you want to happen, then it'll be just fine. You really haven't given any information that the starter is causing your problem, though. You say you have to "start it several times" ... what does that mean? Is it starting or not? Is it you have to crank it several times and it isn't starting? Is it starting then quitting? Could you edit your question and provide more details?

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2. I edited my question. Yeah it starts after several attempts to start it. Sometimes, it starts only on one attempt

Comment: When the battery is able to crank the engine again and again, if all the mechanic can say is "the battery is OK" then the first step is to find another mechanic.

Comment: @WeatherVane. Mechanic says the problem is on the starter.

Comment: So you mean the starter *isn't* cranking the engine, or only *sometimes* cranks the engine? By "cranking" do you mean the engine is turning but not firing?

Comment: @WeatherVane. It does crank. it kinda sounds like when you need a battery change. It always cranks. its just it doesn't start the engine immediately sometimes. Sometimes it starts immediately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is, Is it ok, not to have it fixed? Will this cause problems in the future if I decided not to have it fix?

If the problem is the starter motor itself then leaving it has two potential downsides:

1. It may eventually fail completely - sod's law ensures that if it does so it will be at the most inconvenient time possible, either because you're going to be late for work or you're in the middle of nowhere late at night.
2. You're putting extra wear on the battery - it's small but eventually you'll cause it to wear out and need replacing sooner. Also if you're doing lots of small journeys you're running an increased risk of finding yourself without sufficient charge to start, and as in #1 this will probably happen at the worst possible time.